# Registering an event in a thread with a callback function

Tags: java, multithreading, events, concurrency, callback

I am modifying my server such that every time it accepts a connection it should register a timeout event in a thread with a callback function. The timeout can be any number.

There is only one timeout thread (each connection is not assigned to one separate timeout thread).

How would I go about doing this? I am thinking of starting a thread in main but not sure how to register a timeout event with it and how to pass arguments.

Comment: I do not see any functionality that you require and that are missing from `java.util.Timer` ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
void registerCallback() {
  ses.schedule(new MyCommand(), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

It returns a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which can be used to cancel the execution if you want to, or to obtain a value returned by `MyCommand`.

Should you want to schedule a command that will keep repeating on a timely fashion, you could use other scheduling methods: `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.

If you need to reschedule on some condition only, or with different rates or intervals, one technique I've used is to pass the `ScheduledExecutorService` to your command (ie, `new MyCommand(ses)`) and let it rescheduled itself or a new command with the appropriate delay:

```
class MyCommand implements Runnable {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService ses;
  MyCommand(ScheduledExecutorService ses) { this.ses = ses; }
  private boolean shouldReschedule() { ... }
  private int getRescheduleTimeoutMs() { ... }
  @Override void run() {
    // do work
    ...
    // reschedule if needed
    if (shouldReschedule()) {
      // reschedule this command:
      ses.schedule(this, getRescheduleTimeoutMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      // or else a new one:
      ses.schedule(new MyCommand(ses), ...);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like @Bruno's answer worked for you.  For posterity, another way would just to have a background thread that awakens every second to see if there is a connection established and to check it's age.  If you want to get more fancy you could set a start time and sleep the right amount of seconds.  Something like the following pseudo code:

```
private AtomicReference<Socket> socketTimeoutRef = new AtomicReference<Socket>();
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        SocketTimeout socketTimeout = socketTimeoutRef.get();
        if (socketTimeout == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (socket is closed) {
            socketTimeoutRef.compareAndSet(socketTimeout, null);
        } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= socketTimeout.timeoutMillis) {
            try {
                close the socket;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore exceptions
            }
            socketTimeoutRef.compareAndSet(socketTimeout, null);
        }
    }
}
public void startTimeoutCounter(Socket socket) {
    socketRef.set(new SocketTimeout(socket));
}
private static class SocketTimeout {
    Socket socket;
    long timeoutMillis;
    public SocketTimeout(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        timeoutMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep timely repeating some code, you don't need to write something so complicated and error-prone. There are methods to achieve exactly this, on a way more scalable way, on  the very same interface `ScheduledExecutorService`: `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay`. Should you want to repeat on some condition, or with changing delays, you could pass your `SES` to your `command`, and let it decide if it want to schedule it self (or a new command) again.

Comment: I disagree @Bruno.  Half of this code would have to be duplicated if you were using any of the scheduled methods.  For example, I assume that the other thread may close the thread if it exits cleanly so races to the cancel exist.  I was just trying to be complete.  The only thing that using the executor service saved you from is the `sleep(1000)` loop.

Comment: Gary, sorry, I don't understand what you are worried about (*races to the cancel*?). I'd be glad if you could elaborate on it, and on what this code allows you to do that is not possible (or that is really akward) with the standard ScheduledExecutorService (or ThreadPoolScheduledExecutor, directly). For instance, with the SES approach, you would avoid Thread.sleep(...) (and the checked InterruptedException it throws which you omitted) and the cumbersome null checks and sets -- in other words, exactly half of the code, the boilerplate code.

Comment: The problem with either method is that there is a race to the `socket.close()`.  If the transaction finishes normally (i.e. without the timeout) then I assume `close()` is called.  If it finishes normally at the same time the timeout thread is operating then they both may go to close the socket.  You need protection around that.  The boilerplate code also is dealing with (I assume) a `volatile Socket` so there's a race that the cancel is called and a new socket is opened and the timeout thread misses the interrupt and closes the wrong socket.

Comment: Gray, in Java, `Socket implements Closeable`, **therefore `.close()`  is idempotent**. In other words, **there's no need to protect against 2 closes on the same socket**. Anyways, in the design I propose you would simply and obviously write immutable commands (ie, `class MyCommand implements Runnable { final Socket socket; ... }`), so you wouldn't even have to think about *a race that the cancel is called and a new socket is opened blablabla*. Standard classes and standard practices usually lead to cleaner code!

Comment: Didn't know that socket.close() was `synchronized` which does lessen the race there.  And we agree on the immutable commands.